# pthread_mutex_wait multiple producer and consumer

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, posix, producer-consumer

I was going through [this](http://www.cse.iitd.ernet.in/~sbansal/os/lec/l25.html) and [this](http://www.cse.iitd.ernet.in/~sbansal/os/lec/l24.html) link. Basically, they are discussing why classical single threaded producer consumer design (with `signal` and `wait` does not work for multi-producer scenario). I have one doubt which has been bugging me -

**Argument made by author**
Consider reference code

```
char queue[MAX];  //global
int head = 0, tail = 0; //global
struct cv not_full, not_empty;
struct lock qlock;

void produce(char data) {
  acquire(&qlock);
  if ((head + 1) % MAX  ==  tail) {
    wait(&not_full, &qlock);   //line 1
  }
  queue[head] = data; //line 2
  head = (head + 1) % MAX;
  notify(&not_full);
  release(&qlock);
}

char consume(void) {
  acquire(&qlock);
  if (tail == head) {
    wait(&not_empty, &qlock);
  }
  e = queue[tail];
  tail = (tail + 1) % MAX;
  notify(&not_empty);
  release(&qlock);
  return e;
}
```

In the above code, in case of two producer, `line 1` will be `woken up` in both the producer thread by single consumer (when queue is not full). So both producer can add to the queue leading to queue overflow.

**My doubt**
a. We are protecting the queue with mutex lock. So even if `wait` is woken up on multiple producer thread, only one producer would still have mutex lock - so logically there would be only one producer 'owning' rights to add to queue. Because when we come out of `wait` we would have mutex to be acquired.

**Cavet**
I use POSIX mutex,cond var as reference. However, I do not see article written with POSIX as reference standard.

**Question**
Is my understanding of `wait` specifically `pthread_cond_wait` correct? And with multiple producers, the integrity of the code is still maintained.

Comment: do you really mean `pthread_mutex_wait` or do you mean `pthread_cond_wait`?

Comment: @UmNyobe: Correct I would edit it.

Comment: I'm not entierly sure of what your specific question is, but your code will work with multiple producers/consumers if you convert the 2 `if` statements to `while` statements, and use pthread_cond_broadcast  as the notify() primitive. But as-is, the code risk blowing up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author mentionned at the end of its article under *Semantics of wait() and notify()* that

> notify(cv) wakes up ***all*** threads that are currently waiting on that cv

So your understanding of wait is incorrect, `notify` is meant to be `pthread_cond_broadcast` in posix.

Furthermore the [documentation of pthread_cond_signal](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/pthread_cond_signal.html) stipulates

> The `pthread_cond_signal()` call unblocks ***at least one*** of the threads
>   that are blocked on the specified condition variable cond (if any
>   threads are blocked on cond).

Which is still different from your *"only one producer"* assumption.

As the author shown, the integrity of the code above is not maintained with multiple producers.

**edit:**

The [pseudocode of a condition variable](https://www.andrew.cmu.edu/course/15-440-sp11/applications/ln/lecture7.html) `wait` may look like

```
void wait (condition *cv, mutex *mx) 
{
    mutex_acquire(&c->listLock);  /* protect the queue */
    enqueue (&c->next, &c->prev, thr_self()); /* enqueue */
    mutex_release (&c->listLock); /* we're done with the list */

    /* The suspend and release_mutex() operation should be atomic */
    release_mutex (mx));
    thr_suspend (self);  /* Sleep 'til someone wakes us */

    <-------- notify executes somewhere else

    mutex_acquire (mx); /* Woke up -- our turn, get resource lock */
    return;
}
```

during a `signal` at least one threads in the queue in `suspend` state is awaken. But `pthread` doesnt guarantee ***it will be only one***. Now they are runnable. But they still need to acquire the lock to ensure mutual exclusion between each other.

So when the first releases the mutex, the second takes it and so on.

Which means that one after the other the awaken producers will execute

```
queue[head] = data; //line 2
head = (head + 1) % MAX;
notify(&not_full);
release(&qlock);
```

Comment: Assume more than one thread is woken, then mutex would be acquired - which must be acquired by only one thready - right? This is where I am having confusion. Doesn't the mutex ensure, even if many are woken - pthread_cond_wait (which atomically acquired lock when coming out) must lead to only one thread being truly woken.

Comment: @kumar_m_kiran added further explanations